# Raycast not detecting object

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm new to unity and still learning. I have an object (a tile) at location (-35, 0, -35) and a second object at (-35, 1, -35).  I am firing a raycast from the tile upwards towards the second object (from the tile) using the below code and logging it to see the result.  The unfortunate thing is that it is not detecting it. This is the code:

```
    Vector3 upward= transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
    bool test = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, upward, 2);
    Debug.Log(test);
```

unfortunatly though, the output always returns false.  Is there something I am not understanding?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because of the collider that i had on the object, the raycast started inside the mesh collider and was not detecting it because it was not hitting the collider, only exiting it.